# What resolution can the eeePC 1001HA/1101HA handle with an external monitor plugged in?

Tags: display, resolution, external-display, eee-pc

I would like to buy a new Eee PC 1001HA or 1101HA.
I know the max display resolution is:

- 1024x600 for eeePC 1001
- 1366x768 for eeePC 1101

But what's the maximum resolution of the graphic board when connecting these two computers to *an external LCD monitor*?

Let's say the external monitor supports a full HD resolution of 1920x1080. Are these eeePC graphic boards able to go up to such resolution?

It's really incredible to me how such a useful piece of information is missing everywhere on every ASUS website. EeePCs are very well suited to be connected to external monitor, so I can't believe how difficult is to find out this information. I downloaded the manual, but it's not in there either. So I'm hoping somone has got one and knows the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 1101HA 1920x1200 (WUXGA) works without problems.

1001HA is reported to do at least 1920x1440. According [Intel's specs](https://web.archive.org/web/20100323203940/http://www.intel.com/products/chipsets/gma950/index.htm) GMA 950 (found in 1001HA) is capable of 2048x2536 maximum resolution but I would be surprised to find such a resolution to work with netbooks.

And as Asus's netbooks have D-Sub instead of DVI adapter, the resulting image quality can be rather poor with large resolutions.

Answer (score 2):

I own an Assus EEE901 and a EEE Box, both are able to drive my 24" (1900x1200) monitor. 
I would assume both laptops you mention can do the same.

Comment: i don't think you mean 19000 ;)

Comment: @alpha1: thx, fixed!

Comment: My Full HD Viera TV is not cooperating: I only get 1024x768, which is rather poor. Which OS are you using and have you had to tweak anything yourself?

Comment: I've got (had) Ubuntu installed on both systems. The 901 is no longer in use. I replaced it with a 2nd hand Thinkpad x200 ... what a sweet machine!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Asus has a new version of the Eee out, the Eee PC 1001P. It has a newer, faster, more power efficient processor, and better graphics than the 1001HA. You might be better off getting that. It has a GMA 3150, which is quite capable of driving an external monitor at 1080p, though you probably won't get good framerates for full HD video. The 1001HA has, I think, the GMA950 chipset. My laptop has that, and it runs a 1080p monitor just fine, but again, HD video is very choppy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this does not answer to my question. I'm probably unlucky, no one seems to have that kind of netbook at home to try it.

Comment: I believe it does answer your question, in that yes, it will run at 1080p. But here's some more specific info. The Eee PC 1001HA has the Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 950. According to the Intel documentation, it is capable of a maximum resolution of "Up to 2048x1536 resolution for both analog and digital displays".  http://www.intel.com/products/chipsets/gma950/index.htm