# Does Ubuntu handle the GMA 950 as well as Windows?

Tags: performance, ubuntu-10.10, integrated-graphics

So I notice that eeePC 1001P can handle [a pretty high resolution](https://superuser.com/q/122704/23420) whereas my 1005HA, on Ubuntu, flickers when I even alt+tab. I looked for drivers and it seems they're all bundled into Ubuntu already.

Did I bog down my Ubuntu install, or is linux just worse at GMA than Windows?

Comment: Linux is worse at specific GMA models, afair

Comment: @Sathya this is a GMA 950, FYI.

Comment: so I gather from the title, but I'm not sure which models are the problematic ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel graphics are still a [work in progress](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2010Q3.html), but see the [support matrix](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/user.html) for some examples. If you have the very latest drivers and software it seems to work well. I'm not sure if Ubuntu has the very latest.

Comment: Doesn't seem to mention ASUS on the support matrix. That clears up a lot actually.

Answer (score 0):

it might be related to the default inclusion of compiz if you are using the latest ubuntu.  ripping out compiz might get you some better results(this may preclude you from the latest gnome packages though and force you into xfce or some other alternate desktop)

Comment: I'm on Gnome Shell (Mutter) because Unity wouldn't handle my hardware ...

Comment: i'm using an older acer aspire and got it all tweaked with the intel onboard video working well and actually at a HIGHER resolution than windows supported...idk how or why